# I want to know how to automate a web scrapping task in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

I am attempting to use java script and xpaths to automate the process of checking cut dates for export booking multiple times a day. I use a google sheet to keep track of my bookings and i check all cut dates on my rail company's webpage. there is a password and user name required to get into page ad then some navigation until booking number is entered into search box and a customer is selected from a drop down menu. then after enter button is presses and cut date is given. I have tried using xpath finder on my chrome extensions to figure of my xpath route through the website. I am just not able to make it work no matter what i try. I have tried a few scrapping apps but they seem to focus on pulling info from web pages like amazon. I wanted this to be accomplished through Java script so its free and i can then adopt it to be able to upate other information about my bookings from the carriers websites. This is the code i have so far and my xpaths i have gathered from xpath finder. any help figuring this out would be amazing! it would automate half my job!

```js
function updateBookingDates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var bookingNumber = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

    var url = "https://access.nwcontainer.com/";

    // Login to the website

    var loginPage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

    var loginHtml = loginPage.getContentText();

    var loginDoc = XmlService.parse(loginHtml);

    var loginRoot = loginDoc.getRootElement();

    var username = loginRoot
      .getElement("input", { id: "ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlLogin_UserName" })
      .getAttribute("value")
      .getValue();

    var password = loginRoot
      .getElement("input", { id: "ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlLogin_Password" })
      .getAttribute("value")
      .getValue();

    var formData = {
      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pnlLogin$UserName: username,

      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pnlLogin$Password: password,

      __VIEWSTATE: loginRoot
        .getElement("input", { id: "__VIEWSTATE" })
        .getAttribute("value")
        .getValue(),

      __EVENTVALIDATION: loginRoot
        .getElement("input", { id: "__EVENTVALIDATION" })
        .getAttribute("value")
        .getValue(),

      __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: loginRoot
        .getElement("input", { id: "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" })
        .getAttribute("value")
        .getValue(),

      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pnlLogin$btnLogin: "Log In",
    };

    var options = {
      method: "post",

      payload: formData,

      followRedirects: false,
    };

    var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    // Search for the booking

    var searchUrl = "https://access.nwcontainer.com/LookupBooking.aspx";

    var searchPayload = {
      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBooking: bookingNumber,

      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCustomer: "",

      ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch: "Search",
    };

    var searchOptions = {
      method: "post",

      payload: searchPayload,

      followRedirects: false,

      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    var searchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(searchUrl, searchOptions);

    var searchHtml = searchResponse.getContentText();

    // Parse the search results to find the cut-off date

    var searchDoc = XmlService.parse(searchHtml);

    var searchRoot = searchDoc.getRootElement();

    var cutoff = searchRoot
      .getElement("span", { id: "ContentPlaceHolder1_lblOffHireDate" })
      .getText();

    // Update the sheet with the cutoff date

    sheet.getRange(i, 6).setValue(cutoff);
  }
}
```

the code above it what i tried.